# Bing Search API finds different results from the public search interface

Tags: bing-api

I used the bing search api to search `site:www.article-submissions.biz`, the query string is

```
http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Query=site%3Awww.article-submissions.biz
```

The total results are 7

I search it on bing.com, the result is 45.

Why are the results different in the API from the public search interface?